# Having issue with "DownloadFile" not working in Android (version 10) even after getting app permissions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webclient, android-permissions

I'm a beginner (as in two Udemy C# courses and a couple of tic tac toe & snake game code-along videos on YouTube beginner, so please excuse my ignorance) using Visual Studio 19 and Xamarin for Android to create a web scraper app for my Android phone. The main issue I've been having is when I use the `WebClient` `DownloadFile` method I get a "System.Net.WebException"(System.UnauthorizedAccessException) saying "Access to the path [filename] is denied."

I found a few other stack posts with similar issues and they all said the issue was not checking/granting permissions but even after adding code to request/grant permission I would get the same exception. I may have added the code incorrectly but i didn't think so since when i tested it on an emulator the permissions pop-up seemed to work. Here's the Exception:

```
"Access to the path \"/storage/emulated/0/Download/6855288302363331845.mp4\" is denied."
```

Here's my code for downloading the video from the URI:

```
public static void DownloadVideo(string htmlCode)
        {
            string fullID = GetVideoID(htmlCode);
            string fullLink = GetVideoLink(htmlCode);

            //android filepath (or is it?)
            string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            string file = Path.Combine(directory, fullID + ".mp4");

            //download video
            using (WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient())
            {
                downloadClient.DownloadFile(fullLink, file);
            }

        }
```

I always get the exception on the `downloadClient.DownloadFile(fullLink, file);` line.

I also tried using `MediaStore` but honestly I didn't really understand how that and the context stuff worked.

Here are the permissions I added to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And here's the `OnCreate` code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            

            //get ui controls
            EditText videoUrl = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.urlInput);
            Button processButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            Button dlButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
            Button rsButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            Button permissions = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);
            TextView confirmation = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textConfirmation);
            EditText videoID = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText videoLink = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);

            
            //process
            processButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                string startingUrl = videoUrl.Text.ToString();
                string htmlCode = "";

                if (startingUrl.Contains("tiktok") != true)
                {
                    Core.UrlDownloadAction.UpdateLabel(confirmation, "Invalid Link");
                }
                else
                {
                    htmlCode = Core.UrlDownloadAction.DownloadHTML(startingUrl);

                    videoID.Text = Core.UrlDownloadAction.GetVideoID(htmlCode);
                    videoLink.Text = Core.UrlDownloadAction.GetVideoLink(htmlCode);
                    confirmation.Text = "Successfully Processed";
                    
                }
                

            };

            //download
            dlButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                string startingUrl = videoUrl.Text.ToString();
                string fullVideoID = videoID.Text.ToString();
                string htmlCode = Core.UrlDownloadAction.DownloadHTML(startingUrl);

                
                
                //download video
                if (startingUrl.Contains("tiktok") != true)
                {
                    Core.UrlDownloadAction.UpdateLabel(confirmation, "Invalid Link");
                }
                else
                {
                    //check & request permissions
                    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
                    {
                        RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 257);
                    }
                    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
                    {
                        RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 256);
                    }
                    //download
                    if (htmlCode == "failed")
                    {
                        confirmation.Text = "Invalid HTML";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Core.UrlDownloadAction.DownloadVideo(htmlCode);
                        confirmation.Text = "Successful Download";
                    }
                }

                /*if (!(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)*//* && !(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)*//*)
                {
                    if ((ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)))*//* && (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)))*//*
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Storage permissions are needed to save the file.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    //reqest read/write permissions
                    RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, requestCode: 256);
                    RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, requestCode: 257);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                }*/

            };
            
            rsButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Core.UrlDownloadAction.ResetDownloader(videoUrl, confirmation, videoID, videoLink);
            };

        }
```

I used to have the check permissions code implemented differently (as seen in the commented out code) and originally had it as shown in the video tutorial in the [Android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) but eventually decided to leave it as is.

Any help would be appreciated and I'll try to answer any questions I can. I've gone through a lot of documentation but sometimes I think it's better to get help from someone more experienced than myself.

Comment: I believe you need to use the DownloadManager API to write to the system Download folder

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that. I had tried searching that before but got confused (and admittedly overwhelmed) so I didn't explore it as much as I should have.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Android 6.0, Android needs runtime permissions. And when you want to download the file, the Storage permission are needed.

I make the code sample about how to download form the link with the `DownloadVideo` method you provided. Due to i do not have the video link, i use a image downloading link for reference.

```
  public class Activity_layout1 : Activity
{

    public string TAG
    {
        get
        {
            return "Activity1";
        }
    }
    static readonly int REQUEST_STORAGES = 1;
    static string[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGES = {
    Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
    Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage
};

    View layout;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        var Request_Permission = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_RequestPermission);
        Request_Permission.Click += delegate
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "Show Storage button pressed. Checking permissions.");

            // Verify that all required contact permissions have been granted.
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted
                || ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                // Contacts permissions have not been granted.
                Log.Info(TAG, "Storage permissions has NOT been granted. Requesting permissions.");
                RequestContactsPermissions();
            }
            else
            {
                // Contact permissions have been granted. Show the contacts fragment.
                Log.Info(TAG, "Storage permissions have already been granted.");

            }
        };

        var Download = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_Download);
        Download.Click += delegate
        {

            //android filepath (or is it?)
            string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            string file = Path.Combine(directory, "abc" + ".jpg");

            //download video
            using (WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient())
            {
                downloadClient.DownloadFile("http://www.dada-data.net/uploads/image/hausmann_abcd.jpg", file);
            }

        };

        var Check = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_CheckFile);
        Check.Click += delegate
        {
            string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            string file = Path.Combine(directory, "abc" + ".jpg");
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
                alert.SetTitle("File Check");
                alert.SetMessage("File Exists!!!");
                alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
                {
                    // Ok button click task  
                });
                alert.Show();
            }
        };
    }

    void RequestContactsPermissions()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts)
            || ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts))
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "Displaying storage permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            // Display a SnackBar with an explanation and a button to trigger the request.
            Snackbar.Make(layout, "Storage Permission is needed",
                Snackbar.LengthIndefinite).SetAction("OK", new Action<View>(delegate (View obj)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGES, REQUEST_STORAGES);
                })).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            //  permissions have not been granted yet. Request them directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGES, REQUEST_STORAGES);
        }
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGES)
        {
            // Received permission result for  permission.
            Log.Info(TAG, "Received response for Storage permission request.");

            // Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if ((grantResults.Length == 1) && (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted))
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "Storage permission has now been granted.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "Storage permission was NOT granted.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

On Android 10/Q the used path is not accessable. This has been reported here a hundred times.

You can still get access by adding legacyExternalStorage true to manifest file. This you can also read a hundred times on stackoverflow.

Comment: There's that fabled stackoverflow welcome. Thanks for the input, I'll look into it now that I know what I didn't know. Any chance you want to link one of those hundreds of threads?

Comment: if you think a question is a duplicate, then vote to close as a duplicate.